# Statistical significance of classifier mean error rates

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistics

Given:

Error rates of 3 classifier types (CT) of performing 10 times a 5-fold cross validation
For each CT the mean error rate out of the 10*5=50 error rates is calculated

Goal:

Is the CT with the lowest mean error rate statistically significant the best? Or has it “randomly” the smallest error value?

Solution:

Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test: Pair-wise comparison of the 50 error rates of the best CT with the 50 of the other CTs. So if the first CT is the best one I have to check: CT1-CT2 and CT1-CT3. If both checks result a statistical significance it suggests that CT1 is rightly the best.

Question:

Is this an appropriate procedure? Or would you suggest me an other procedure?